# How to create a custom html tag using the spark viewengine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

I've heard or read somewhere (can't recall where) that the spark view engine supports the notion of defining custom html tags. I would like to use this for rounded corners. Which in our HTML consist out of 6 different div's wrapped around the actual content. If I could replace this with  or something like that it would make things much more readable. Is it correct that spark can do this? And if so how do I use this, is there some documentation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a partial in Spark looks just like a custom HTML tag, but is really just a little syntactic sugar. Check [this page](http://sparkviewengine.com/documentation/organizingcontent#Implicitpartialrendering) out for more information.

Comment: Great just what I was looking for, didn't think of it as syntactic sugar but I guess it really is :)